# Reduce .git size in space checkout case

Tags: git

In sparse checkout case, git log still show all logs, event if the log is not related to sparse checked out files.

Is it possible to reduce .git folder size? Only keep information that related to sparse checked out files, and I still can work on it, e.g. commit, push and pull.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no.

There are some recent efforts by Microsoft in this direction that have been (perhaps surprisingly) well-received in the git community, but if this arrives in stock git, it is still some time in the future.

[Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/5rtlk0/git_virtual_file_system_from_microsoft/) , 
[Ars Technica](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2017/02/microsoft-hosts-the-windows-source-in-a-monstrous-300gb-git-repository/)

(Git also has shallow clones, which reduce your history and save .git space. But that is another issue entirely and not what you're asking about.)